# How to style QSpliter handle and scrollbar like this?

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qtstylesheets

Screep-shot link: http://qt-apps.org/CONTENT/content-pre1/119860-1.png

I would like to customize the look of scrollbar handle and QSplitter handle like the screen shot link above. I know it can be done from stylesheet. However I have no idea how to achieve this. Holp someone can share a small example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a style sheet, that's a [QPlastiqueStyle](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/gallery-plastique.html).

```
setStyle(new QPlastiqueStyle);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! Just add: QApplication::setStyle(new QPlastiqueStyle());

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to customize the splitters instead of changing the whole style:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet(
    "QSplitter::handle:vertical   {height: 6px; image: url(images/vsplitter.png);}"
    "QSplitter::handle:horizontal {width:  6px; image: url(images/hsplitter.png);}"
    );
```